# Slowing down looping animation as3

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, coin-flipping

This is the first time I've ever posted in a forum, so thanks in advance for anyone who takes the time to read/answer this question.

What I'm trying to create is basically a flipping coin animation, which starts off turning very fast and then slows down to stop with a (randomly generated) side facing upwards after about 8 seconds.

I've done the animation of a complete flip, which lasts about half a second, and made it in to a movieclip... now I'm stuck!

Any ideas how I might go about doing this in actionscript3?

Comment: Hard to tell where you are stuck. Please tell us what you have tried and why it doesn't work. If you need to have a pause between MovieClip plays then use the `Timer` class. Or if you need exact control of MovieClip frames, the `MovieClip` class should provide you with everything you need.

Comment: To be honest I haven't really tried anything in AS because I'm a complete noob. What I'd normally do would be to simply animate it slowing down in the timeline, but if it's possible to do it in AS then I'd much rather take that route. I don't need it to pause, I just need it to play the movie clip about 50 times, each time slightly slower than the last

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way around this would be to use some very basic actionscript. First, create 2 animations (One heads, one tails). Now, you only need a single frame for this and don't need to place the movieclips on the stage. Use the following or similar code:

```
var whichSide:int = 0;
var coin1:coinAnimation1 = new coinAnimation1();
var coin2:coinAnimation2 = new coinAnimation2();

whichSide = math.Round(math.Random(1));

if(whichSide == 1)
{
addChild(coin1);
}
else
{
addChild(coin2);
}
```

Just don't forget to right click the movieclip and export for actionscript, giving the movieclips the class of: coinAnimation1 and coinAnimation2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, that's fantastic :) Should I then have the two movieclips just animating getting slower, or is it possible to do that bit with AS too?

Comment: Well, it's easier to animate it getting slower if you can figure out how, but long animations have larger filesizes. If you do it by actionscript, it'll be a tiny operation! 

There's about 3 or 4 methods by which you could do it using Actionscript - the cheapest one being to actually slow down the frame rate gradually until it reaches zero!

`stage.addeventlistener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, slowDown)
function slowDown(event:Event)
{
stage.framerate *= 0.95;
}`
That could work

Comment: Thanks for that - I really appreciate it, but I have other animation going on at the same time so I can't lower the frame rate. File size doesn't really matter for this project, so I think I'll just animate it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished such animation on ´Keyframes´ using the Tweener class. You can easily tween on the keyframe parameter with specific transition...

Basic example:

```
Tweener.addTween(myMovieClip, {_frame:10, time:2.5});
```

More information about Tweener [here](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/)